# The MySQL server crashed when I try to set remote access using 'grant'

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I type the commands below:

```
mysql –u root -p
Grant all privileges on *.* to root@”%” identified by “rootpassword” with grant option;
Grant all privileges on mysitedb.* to root@localhost;
```

then the server crashed：

> Could not establish database connection. Please check the username,
>   password and hostname in the config file, and if necessary set up the
>   appropriate MySQL user and privileges.

Comment: so，what should I do to rescue my server ?

Comment: tried, there's no error...

Comment: mysql     2947  0.0  2.0 1023380 168496 ?      Sl   Jul25   5:56 mysqld --skip-grant-tables
root      7219  0.0  0.0  31716  3620 pts/1    S+   02:17   0:00 mysql -u root -p
mysql     8542 15.0  1.5 821744 130400 ?       Ssl  03:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      8569  0.0  0.0   7712  1244 pts/2    S+   03:18   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the grand statement in to below one, then solved:

```
mysql –u root -p
Grant all privileges on *.* to root@”%” identified by “rootpassword” with grant option;
Grant all privileges on mysitedb.* to root@localhost identified by “rootpassword” with grant option;
```